# Combining Functions to reduce complexity

Tags: javascript

What would be the best way to make these three functions more efficient?  They share logic.

```
function setBoxWidth(type) {
   var boxWidth;

   if (type) {
       boxWidth = 308;
   } else {
       boxWidth = 400;
   }

   return boxWidth;
}

function setAspectWidth(type) {
   var bw;

   if (type) {
       bw = 192;
   } else {
       bw = 100;
   }
   return bw;
}

function setAspectHeight(type) {
   var bh;

   if (type) {
       bh = 47;
   } else {
    bh = 100;
   }
   return bh;
}
```

I access them like so:

```
function useJcrop(img, type, boxWidth) {
    var aspect,
        bh = setAspectHeight(type),
        bw = setAspectWidth(type),
        bWidth  =setBoxWidth(type);
}
```

Comment: I don't see where type is assigned a value.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I made the edit.  It is an argument in the useJcrop function.

Comment: Do they have to be funtions?

Comment: What sort of value is "type" supposed to be?  A number? A string? Why is it called "type" if it's basically just used as a boolean flag?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com (or needs to be clarified).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to make these three functions more efficient is to avoid writing them.

```
function useJcrop(img, type, boxWidth) {
    var aspect,
        bh = type ? 308 : 400,
        bw = type ? 192 : 100,
        bWidth = type ? 47 : 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
function useJcrop(img, type, boxWidth) {
    var aspect,
        bh = type ? 308 : 400,
        bw = type ? 192 : 100,
        bWidth  = type ? 47 : 100
}
```

It's a lot less code.

I suggest you put those numbers into descriptive variables if possible, though.  Or calculate them programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
function setBoxWidth(type) {
   return type ? 308 : 400;
}

function setAspectWidth(type) {
   return (type) ? 192 : 100;
}

function setAspectHeight(type) {
   return (type) ? 47 : 100;
}
```

Hard to get simpler than that with functions. You should probably consider encapsulating all this information in an Object, however, since type is basically shared state across the 3.

```
function CroppedImage(type)
{
   this.type=type;

   this.getBoxWidth= function() {
      return type ? 308 : 400;
   }
   /... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Try something like this?

```
bh = type ? 47 : 100;
bw = type ? 192 : 100;
bWidth = type ? 308 : 400;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the naming of your functions is confusing. They do not set anything (except local variables), instead they return a value. Thus I would call them getFoo(), getBar() and so on. Furthermore you do not need the local variables.

```
function getAspectWidth(type) {
  if (type) {
   return 192;
  } else {
   return 100;
  }
}
```

Other than that I wouldn't do anything else. It is more readable and understandable than your version.

Or you could make use of the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#JavaScript)

```
function getAspectWidth(type) {
  return type ? 192 : 100;
}
```

which is even more concise.